# Android: having different title name and launcher name

Tags: android, titlebar, launcher

I have an application with a Custom Title Bar in which I have used in Image as the title background or title image and I have removed the string of the title.

Now the problem is that if I remove the string from the title since I am using my own customized titlebar, there is no launcher name for my application (the name that is displayed below the icon of your application).

If I select noTitleBar for my activity, then it won't show my customized titlebar as well. I don't know why Android takes the string for title and launcher from the same resource..it doesn't make sense to do so.

Here is my code of customized title bar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="TitlebarBackgroundStyle">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/titlebar</item>
</style>
<style name="Theme.MyCustomTheme" parent="android:Theme"> 
    <item       name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/TitlebarBackgroundStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">54dp</item>

</style>
```

Any suggestions???

Answer (score 0):

The application-name that is shown for your app is defined in the Android Manifest in the `<application>`-tag:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="Your App Name">
  ...
</application>
```

If you implemented a `TitleBar` yourself, you should be able to not print this string in the bar (as you want it) by simply removing the `TextView` from the Layout.

However it needs to be set, otherwise (as you noticed yourself) the app won't have a name in the launcher.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more. I don't have any TextView in my Customized Title bar because I am just using an Image that has also some text printed in it.. it would be great if you elaborate a bit more..

Comment: Maybe I'm on the wrong horse here. Can you post your XML-Layout and the piece of code for your `TitleBar`?

Comment: Okay, i see. You only set the Background for your `TitleBar`. You can check on [this tutorial](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-create-custom-titlebar) and leaf out the `TextView`s, so your Bar will only show your Background Image. You could also place a `ImageView` in it.